# iphone Development - pick unique image from array problem, syntax help

Tags: iphone

Code:

```
//pick one filename
int numFileNames = [imageArray count];
int chosen = arc4random() % numFileNames;
NSString *oneFilename = [imageArray objectAtIndex: chosen];
```

thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain further and also fix the formatting of the top (I would if I could but I don't have enough rep)

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?  Do you want us to provide code for each step?

Comment: yes if you can, i have problem with the syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not here to do your work for you.  If you have specific questions about elements that you are having trouble with, we'd be glad to answer those.

Comment: thats ok, can you help me add a loop to check if the image is already added in this array (for unique purpose).

NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int c=0;c<2;c++)
{
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageBall%d.png", c];
        [imageArray addObject: imageName];
}
int numFileNames = [imageArray count];
int chosen = arc4random() % numFileNames;
NSString *oneFilename = [imageArray objectAtIndex: chosen];

Answer (score 0):

There's one error in your NSMutableArray:

You need to initialize it first.

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

;)

and here's a suggestion, if you do not necessarily require the interface builder's assistance, you might want to consider cocos2d. The stuffs you wanted to do can be done easily in it.

--
as for step 3. Do a random pick using Rand(), make a loop to check if the selected image is already added in an array (this array is for picked images), if it's in the array randomize again, if not then add in into the picked array, and do ball1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectatindex:randomNum]];

Comment: i need to use the interface builder in this project,
any ideas with steps 3 & 4 ?

Comment: can you help me up with the syntax of the steps?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify the issue at hand, it just mentions that the developer wants to store a unique image name in array, so coding can be done:

NSMutableArray *arrImages = [NSMutableArray new];

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageBall%d",i];

    //Here we can check whether image is already added or not.
    if (![arrImages contains Object:imgName]) {
        [arrImages addObject:imgName];
    }
}

int choosen = arc4random() % (int)arrImages.count;

NSString *imageFileName = arrImages[choosen];
```